# Java code using JGit ignoring the set credentials in push operation

Tags: java, bitbucket, push, jgit

I am using JGit library in my java program to push two programatically updated files to bitbucket.
When i run this program locally then it pushes the files correctly to remote however with my personal git username password which is configured for my local terminal based git activities and totaly ignores the technical user's credentials set in the program. I want the commit to happen by the technical user and not my personal id.
Why the JGit is ignoring the set credentials.

Below is the code

````
try (Grgit grgit = Grgit
        .open(openOp -> {
          openOp.setCredentials(new Credentials(ProjectProperties.getBitBucketUser(),
              ProjectProperties.getBitBucketPwd()));
          openOp.setDir(".");
        })) {
      grgit.add(addOp -> addOp
          .setPatterns(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("fil1.properties", "fil2.properties"))));
      grgit.commit(commitOp -> commitOp
          .setMessage(
              " Updating release details in release.md & release.properties"));
      grgit.push();
      String username = grgit.getRepository().getCredentials().getUsername();
      String passw = grgit.getRepository().getCredentials().getPassword();
      logger.info("*** {} ** {}**", username, passw);
      return true;
    }```

To add more dtails about execution:

This code is part of gradle custom plugin code and been executed from gradle custom task execution from command line.
````

Comment: Just to confirm - Does the log output show the technical users credentials, or your personal ones ?

Comment: yes it shows the technical user's credentials. The log i have to put just to confirm if they are getting set correctly or not and Yes by the logs, its technical user's credentials only.